# How to mail with the use of UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiwebview, ios-simulator

I am using  a UIWebView and i have written this code

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hey, my id is abc@xyz.com"];

[aboutWebView loadHTMLString:str baseURL:nil];
```

Now In this code I want to detect that id and I want the option that user can do mail to this id

I am able to detect the link but nothing happen after it. i am using simulator.

Comment: any reason why you're not using `<a href="mailto:abc@xyz.com">abc@xyz.com</a>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mail.app is not install on the iPhone simulator.  You will need to test that part of your code on an actual device.

Comment: thanks it is working on device , i was testing it in simulator

Answer (score 1):

You can use mailto function and then
U can call following function:

```
  - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

      if ([[[request URL] scheme] isEqual:@"mailto"]) {

          [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[request URL]];
          return NO;
      }

      return YES; 
 }
```

U need to set delegate too